# configuring python logger to throw exception when it can't write to file

Tags: python, debugging, python-2.7, logging

I'm trying to use python's [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) class, and encountering an issue where nothing gets written to the log file. [According to the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#exceptions-raised-during-logging), the general rule is the class won't tell you about a problem while executing:

> "The logging package is designed to swallow exceptions which occur
>   while logging in production"

But I'm interested to understand any issues `logging` is encountering. The doc goes on to mention you can set a module level variable, raiseExceptions to see some more verbosity.

My question is, how do I set that and/or is there a more direct way to go about debugging this sort of issue?

For reference, here is my implementation of `logging` (python 2.7):

```
numeric_log_level = getattr(logging, args.loglevel.upper(), None)
if not isinstance(numeric_log_level, int):
     raise ValueError('Invalid log level: %s' % args.loglevel)
logging.basicConfig\
    (filename=args.logfile, level=numeric_log_level, format="%(asctime)s - [client] - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked to goes on to mention it's already enabled:

> The default value of raiseExceptions is True.

Essentially exceptions for misconfigured logging will by default be printed the `stderr`. So if you want to see any of these problems, watch the output of your app if you are running it in a terminal.

If you are running it as a service or daemon, make sure you direct the stderr to a file. There are many different ways to do this depending on how you are daemonizing your script, but one common way is

```
python script.py 2> /path/to/log_exceptions
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I am running it in a terminal, but not seeing any exceptions, and I have a logging stmt at startup so I should see something right away if there is a problem. Instead I get nothing and no log file.

Comment: What happens when u simply use `logging.info('test')`?

Comment: After redeploying to another host it works. Still not sure what was causing it.